# Display users shift with from and to date in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following table which contains date and user shift.
[image]

In the view i have to display in tabular form `from_date`[Shift start date] `to_date`[Shift end date.] and `shift_id`  of users.It seems to be complex.I'm thinking of using "`group by`" but I'm not able to do it.If you guys can just give me the query i can display it. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to get all the shifts for a particular user, to display? What's wrong with `user.shifts` and then iterate through them in the view?

Comment: also, what is `shift_date` in the above table?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to select start date and end date in one query. If so, the query could be like this:

```
SELECT a.*, (SELECT min(shift_date) FROM shifts
             WHERE user_id = a.user_id AND shift_date > a.shift_date) end_date
  FROM shifts a
```

You can adapt this query according to your requirements and convert it into Rails' query.